# Adminhtml grid inline editing - won't work

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, edit, inline

Working on a new module which will gather most important details for products in one grid. Grid is already prepared and working fine but now I need to add inline editing functionality :)
What steps needs to be done to achieve it ?
Or if I could(how?) call action Edit and modify record in separate form then save it?
If possible please give me an example?
Already tried [Inline editing in Magento](https://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/)
But it seems not work, probably I did not implemented js properly. I can't find where it should be placed. Javascript itself is in the phtml so in layout there should be a reference so it is there but still ... doesn't work

```
< layout >
< adminhtml_sales_index >
    < reference name="js">
       <block type="core/template" template="inchoo/orders/inline-edit.phtml"/>
    < / reference >
< / adminhtml_sales_index >
```

< / layout >

phtml content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateTitle(button, fieldId)
{
echo 'Ajax request';
new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::helper('inchoo_orders')->getUrl('*/*/updateTitle') ?>', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: { id: fieldId, title: $(button).previous('input').getValue() }
    });
}
```

Can't find updateTitle function (js) ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create a simple module as Alan has shown in your link. You must follow exact steps.

You have just shown your partial layout file. And it still has few problems. You shouldn't have any spaces in layout file, especially within `<` and `>` tags.

This is what Alan has mentioned in his article:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_[modulename]_index>
        <reference name="js">
            <block type="core/template" template="namespace/modulename/inline-edit.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_[modulename]_index>
</layout>
```

Here you will need to change `[modulename]` with your own modulename.

**So what's the modulename?**

This is what you have named in your `etc/config.xml` file:

See part of the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Module_NameSpace>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Module_NameSpace>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <modulename>
                <class>Module_NameSpace_Block</class>
            </modulename>
       </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

I hope you know how to develop a simple magento admin module. If you don't then [read here](http://www.multidots.com/step-by-step-guide-for-magento-module-development).

Other than this, Alan's article is pretty much straight forward and it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, must say that I actually did everything exactly as in tutorial. All the paths seems to be ok but it still won't read my script, regardless of what I'm doing, tested all possible ways .... with no luck. ;(
Of course I will continue to learn and will do some research.

Comment: Here is my config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <inchoo_orders>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </inchoo_orders>
    </modules>
 <adminhtml>
  <layout>
   <updates>
    <orders>
     <file>inchoo-orders.xml</file>
    </orders>
   </updates>
  </layout>
 </adminhtml>... of course its the most interesting part so as you can see, I changed it to the correct form ... but it doesn't helped.

Comment: same with inchoo-orders.xml which is my layout file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_orders_index>
        <reference name="js">
            <block type="core/template" template="inchoo/orders/inline-edit.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_orders_index>
</layout>
if there is still something wrong, what it is ? ;(